# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of undefined "google chrome extension"

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension, youtube, console.log

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of undefined

```
window.onload = function() {

var videoUrls = window.ytplayer.config.args.url_encoded_fmt_stream_map.split(',').map(function(item) {
    return  item.split("&").reduce(function(pre, cur){ 

        console.log(pre, cur); 
    });
});

    console.log("Our extension has loaded :)", videoUrls);
}
```

My problem is in  the following code,

```
window.ytplayer.config.args.url_encoded_fmt_stream_map.split(',').map(function(item)
```

Comment: `window.ytplayer` is undefined - where do you think it is defined?

Comment: That is probably because you're doing this in a content script which has a different context then the page that has the `window.ytplayer` property. Take a look at [Insert code into the page context using a content script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/insert-code-into-the-page-context-using-a-content-script)

Answer (score 0):

**window.ytplayer** is not defined most probably. If that is defined too, then it does not contain config property on it.
You can write it like this.

```
var videoUrls = window.ytplayer && 

    window.ytplayer.config.args.url_encoded_fmt_stream_map.split(',').map(function(item) {
        return  item.split("&").reduce(function(pre, cur){ 

            console.log(pre, cur); 
        });
    });
```